# Regex find all Labels in a mulit-value taxononomy field

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I have the following regex

```
\b(?!^;#)\w+\s*\w+\|\b
```

and this sample string.

```
-1;#Class Study|0b4dac95-9e17-4af9-b849-6d283a99b561;#-1;#Matrix|dda77641-7b25-40f9-bb65-a0bca13776d3";
```

I need to just match the label which comes after the ;#

```
       string multipleFieldValue = "-1;#Class Study|0b4dac95-9e17-4af9-b849-6d283a99b561;#-1;#Matrix|dda77641-7b25-40f9-bb65-a0bca13776d3";
        var regex = new Regex(@"\b(?!^;#)\w+\s*\w+\|\b");
        string[] labels = multipleFieldValue.Split(new[] { ";#" },StringSplitOptions.None );
        var matches = regex.Matches(multipleFieldValue);


        Assert.AreEqual(2, matches.Count);
```

currently this returns the label but also returns the | 
I want to eliminate the | as well

Comment: This part `(?!^;#)` will never match (in a negative way) when a `\w` comes after it.

Comment: I'd throw away the word boundares and just go with `(?<=;#)[^|]*(?=\|$)`

Comment: For `(?!^;#)`, neither `;` nor `#` are a word `\w`, so it will never be matched (in a negative way) when the next character should be a word `\w`. So, it is basically not being used.

Comment: And if you're just looking to find the labels, no need for split.

Comment: (?<=;#)[^|]*(?=\|$) returns zero matches

Comment: `(?<=;#)[^|]*(?=\||$)` returns zero matches? How about `(?<=;#)[^|]*` ?

Comment: returns incorrect values. {Class Study,-1#Matrix}

Comment: It returns anything between `;#` and `|`. That's the two delimiters you set. If it's not correct, then the form is not correct the way you set up the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the `|` and word boundary in a lookahead

```
\b(?!^;#)\w+\s*\w+(?=[?^(|)]\b)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vB6nE1/1)

Comment: what if i need the label | termId returned? ie {Class Study|0b4dac95-9e17-4af9-b849-6d283a99b561 , Matrix|dda77641-7b25-40f9-bb65-a0bca13776d3}